# Passing arrays through different classes

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting a player input array that first sorts it from least to most then transfers from one class to a class that checks it against a random array. Here's what I have so far. The checker class is only returning 0's and int counter almost always=4. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for the help!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] player=new int[5]; 
        int[] computer=new int[5];
//creates random numbers to array and asks player if they want to play again
        player_input(player);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(player));
        checker(player,computer,cash,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5);
// calling the functions
        }
```

Is it something wrong in my main method?

```
public static int[] player_input(int player[]) {
        String value;
        int ivalue;
        int count=0;
        int temp;
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++) {
            count++;
            try{
                value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Enter Number "+count+": ","Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
                player[i] = ivalue;
            }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                //handles non int's
            }
            }
//sorting the array so it can match
            if (ivalue > -1 && ivalue<41) {
                player[i] = Integer.parseInt(value);
                for(int j=i+1;j<=4;j++) {
                    if(player[i]>player[j]) {
                        temp=player[i];
                        player[i]=player[j];
                        player[j]=temp;
                    }
        return player;
    }
```

Then player input goes to the checker which is only giving out 0's and counter doesn't input the correct amount.

```
    public static int checker(int[] player, int computer[],int cash,int count1,int count2,int count3,int count4, int count5) {
        int counter=0;
        for (int i=0;i<=4;++i) {
            if(player[i]==computer[i]) {
                System.out.println(player[i]);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter==0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You won nothing, peasent, your total is: $"+cash,"BAD HUMAN",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if(counter==1) {
            count1++;
            cash=cash+100;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations! You got: "+counter+" right for $100! Your total is: $"+cash,"GOOD HUMAN",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
//... goes to counter==5
        return cash;
    }
```

Comment: don't post all the code. only post the code where you have problem

Comment: You've shown a lot of code, but none of the code that passes the array between the two methods. Neither of them ever calls the other, so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for showing too much code, editing it down to make it more readable.

Comment: player_input method never sets any value into player array

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the retun/output of the functions?

The functions `public static int checker` and `public static int[] player_input` have return types of `int` and `int[]` respectively and values are returned on both of the functions.

It would appear that in the main, both functions are called however the values returned aren't used. Should `player_input(player);` be replaced with `player = player_input(player);`

Also worth nothing that within `player_input` the input argument int[] player never gets updated which could also be the issue. Does the line `player[i] = ivalue;` need adding as the last line in the try scope giving the following

```
try{
    value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Number "+count+": ","Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
    player[i] = ivalue;
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    //handles non int's
}
```

Comment: I added ```player = player_input(player);``` However, the player array is still only returning 0's in ```public static int checker```. I also noticed that it is only returning 4 elements when there should be 5. Could it have something to do with when its being sorted? `    for(int j=i+1;j<=4;j++) {
     if(player[i]>player[j]) {
      temp=player[i];
      player[i]=player[j];
      player[j]=temp;
     } `

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comment, it appears that the player array isn't updated in the `player_input` function

Comment: In Java all arrays are Objects and if you mutate an object inside a method this is reflected. This would only be necessary when the method would make a copy of the array before mutating it and then return the copied and mutated array as a new object instance

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Java but Andreas is correct `player_input(player);` would work. however within `player_input` the input argument `player` never gets updated which is the issue I believe

Comment: Ahh, that was a silly mistake! It is still outputting 0s however? Also I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you add the line `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(player));` after the line `player_input(player);` this will output exactly what's in the array

Comment: It seems to be only recording the last input. For context I entered [1,2,3,4,5] and it returned [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]

Comment: Can you update you question to reflect your current code. we're getting there if it's now recording some input but it seems a little odd that it's not recording the rest

Comment: @Thickens it looks like your sort is the problem.

Comment: Ok, updated the code, should I add another for loop and seperate it from input, for the sorting to be correct, or is there another way to sort arrays?

Comment: So if you are indeed entering `1,2,3,4,5` and it is printing out `[0,0,0,0,5]` then the issue is with the data entry function `player_input` not with the sorting. It might be best to tackle it as 2 problems. Firstly get the data input correct so that if you enter say `7,4,6,2,5` it outputs `[7,4,6,2,5]`

Comment: It is something wrong with the sorting. I commented off the sorting and it returned correctly!

Comment: Ahh okay, so how are you trying to sort them, could you not just use `Java.util.Arrays.sort(player)` to sort your array?

Comment: That worked! To be honest I just found that code off of stackoverflow to sort the array. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with sorting the `player` array and not assigning player in `player_input` correctly. This is `player_input` working as intended.

```
    public static int[] player_input(int player[]) {
        String value;
        int ivalue;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++) {
            count++;
            try{
                value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Enter Number "+count+": ","Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
            }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                //handle exception here
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"What are you doing?! Enter a number not words fool!","BAD HUMAN",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Enter Number "+count+": ","Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
        if (ivalue > -1 && ivalue<41) {
                player[i]=ivalue;
            }
        else {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please pick a number between 0-40","BAD HUMAN",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Enter Number "+count+": ","Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
             }
        }
        java.util.Arrays.sort(player);
        return player;
    }
```